# JavaScript: is there any advantage in wrapping everything in a variable?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I've seen several times the following JS coding style:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    foo.run();
});

var foo = {
    bar: null,
    baz: null,

    run: function() {
        foo.init();
    },
    init: function() {
        foo.bar = 1;
    }
    ...
};
```

So basically everything except `addEventListener` is wrapped in a JS object. Is this any good? Why?

Comment: Ah....Sorry for my mistake. Just corrected it.

Comment: this is done to control the visibility of member functions and/or variables.

Comment: I see only one variable, `foo`? Against what other style do you want to compare this?

Comment: @Bergi All other variables or functions are wrapped in `foo`. So with this style there is only on variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this (and also with functions instead of objects, as that gives you local scope) avoids putting to much stuff into the global namespace where it may conflict with other things.

That is especially important if you want to have modular, re-usable code (where you don't know that the application you are being dropped in to doesn't already make use of `window.init` or `window.bar`.

Basically, this is the same "global variables are bad" discussion you can have in any language.

Comment: Would it be better to use closure to fully hide the member functions and variables?